# Determine critical points of 2 variable functions without 2nd derivative test

Tags: calculus

I'm new to two variable calculus and having trouble classifying critical points for some functions which the second derivative test isn't really applicable.

E.g.

$$f(x,y) = x^2+y^2+x^2y+4 $$

$f_x=2x+2xy=0$

$f_y=2y+x^2=0$

Critical Point $(0,0)$

But I don't know how to determine the nature of this critical point.

Answer (score 1):

Express your objective function as:
$$f(x,y)=x^2(1+y)+y^2+4.$$
Note that in the close neighborhood of $(0,0)$, the objective function is greater than or equal to $4$, hence $f(0,0)=4$ is the local minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Two more critical points are $(\sqrt 2,-1)$ and $(-\sqrt 2,-1)$. For finding the nature we use the hessian matrix as following $$H=\begin{bmatrix}2+2y&2x\\2x& 2y\end{bmatrix}$$The eigenvalues of $H$ for $(\pm \sqrt 2,-1)$ are $$\lambda (\lambda+2)-8=0\\\to \lambda_1=2,\lambda_2=-4$$therefore the points $(\pm \sqrt 2,-1)$ are saddle points. For $(0,0)$ we have $H\succeq 0$. Hence $(0,0)$ is a local minimum.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it....